# Convert table to json

Tags: text-processing, json

I have a large table of data that I would like to convert to json and am not sure if a tool like jq, mlr, or similar would be able to perform such a task without having to resort to my poor awk skills.

Sample table:

```
Balance_sheet for AAPL:

                                                        2023-09-30      2022-09-30      2021-09-30      2020-09-30
Treasury Shares Number                                         0.0             NaN             NaN             NaN
Ordinary Shares Number                               15550061000.0   15943425000.0   16426786000.0   16976763000.0
```

Preferred output:

```
{
    "Balance_sheet for AAPL": {
        "Treasury Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "0.0",
            "2022-09-30": "NaN",
            "2021-09-30": "NaN",
            "2020-09-30": "NaN"
        },
        "Ordinary Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "15550061000.0",
            "2022-09-30": "15943425000.0",
            "2021-09-30": "16426786000.0",
            "2020-09-30": "16976763000.0"
        }
    }
}
```

The following format would also work but less desired:

```
{
    "Balance_sheet for AAPL": {
        "2023-09-30": {
            "Treasury Shares Number": "0.0",
            "Ordinary Shares Number": "15550061000.0"
        },
        "2022-09-30": {
            "Treasury Shares Number": "NaN",
            "Ordinary Shares Number": "15943425000.0"
        },
        "2021-09-30": {
            "Treasury Shares Number": "NaN",
            "Ordinary Shares Number": "16426786000.0"
        },
        "2020-09-30": {
            "Treasury Shares Number": "NaN",
            "Ordinary Shares Number": "16976763000.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a sane method of accomplishing this?

Comment: I would reach for Python or some other higher level language, but perhaps you could make some progress using awk's support for [fixed width fields](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-awk-programming/9781788391030/77fb8fc3-4004-423e-9765-afced15835f3.xhtml).

Comment: Does your table use tabs between columns or are they fixed width?

Comment: @Shawn fixed width, spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `perl`:

```
$ perl -MJSON::PP -ae '
  if (/^(.*):$/) {$sheet = $1}
  elsif (/^\h+\d/) {$n = (@dates = @F)}
  elsif (/^(.*?)((?:\h+)\H+){$n}$/) {
    $i = -$n;
    $j{$sheet}->{$1} = {map {$_ => $F[$i++]} @dates}
  }
  END {print JSON::PP->new->pretty->encode(\%j)}' your-file
{
   "Balance_sheet for AAPL" : {
      "Ordinary Shares Number" : {
         "2023-09-30" : "15550061000.0",
         "2020-09-30" : "16976763000.0",
         "2022-09-30" : "15943425000.0",
         "2021-09-30" : "16426786000.0"
      },
      "Treasury Shares Number" : {
         "2020-09-30" : "NaN",
         "2023-09-30" : "0.0",
         "2021-09-30" : "NaN",
         "2022-09-30" : "NaN"
      }
   }
}
```

Which distinguishes 3 types of lines in that input based on regular expressions:

- those that end in `:` which determine the current "sheet" (the keys in the top level objects)
- lines that start with at least one (`+`) `\h`orizontal space followed by one `\d`ecimal digit which are the dates (keys in the third level objects), we record them in the `@dates` array and their number in `$n`.
- Lines that contain at least `$n` blank-delimited fields, where the part before the last `$n` fields makes up the key in the second-level object, and we build the third level object for that key using the `@dates` as keys and those last `$n` fields as values.
- anything else (which in the sample input is just the empty lines) is ignored.

Note that as the JSON objects are the representations of perl associative arrays, the order of the members within them will be random. You can get a consistent order by setting the `canonical` flag (`JSON::PP->new->pretty->canonical->encode(\%j)`) where each object will have members sorted by key.

If it's important that the order of fields in the JSON objects reflect the order in the table, as mentioned in `perldoc JSON::PP`, you can *tie* those arrays to different sorts of hashes that preserve ordering using things like

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MTie::Hash::Indexed -MJSON::PP -ae '
  BEGIN{tie %j, $m = "Tie::Hash::Indexed"}
  if (/^(.*):$/) {tie my %s, $m; $j{$sheet = $1} = \%s}
  elsif (/^\h+\d/) {$n = (@dates = @F)}
  elsif (/^(.*?)((?:\h+)\H+){$n}$/) {
    tie my %s, $m;
    $i = -$n;
    %s = map {$_ => $F[$i++]} @dates;
    $j{$sheet}->{$1} = \%s
  }
  END {print JSON::PP->new->pretty->encode(\%j)}' your-file
{
   "Balance_sheet for AAPL" : {
      "Treasury Shares Number" : {
         "2023-09-30" : "0.0",
         "2022-09-30" : "NaN",
         "2021-09-30" : "NaN",
         "2020-09-30" : "NaN"
      },
      "Ordinary Shares Number" : {
         "2023-09-30" : "15550061000.0",
         "2022-09-30" : "15943425000.0",
         "2021-09-30" : "16426786000.0",
         "2020-09-30" : "16976763000.0"
      }
   }
}
```

`Tie::Hash::Indexed` (`libtie-hash-indexed-perl` Debian package) is one of several such modules that provide ordered hashes.

In case that's important, for a format closer to your expected format with 4-space indentation and spaces after but not before the `:`s, replace `pretty` with `indent->indent_length(4)->space_after` (`indent_length(2)` for `jq`-style pretty-printing).

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    inStep = 4
    print "{"
}

sub(/:$/,"") {
    indent = inStep
    printf "%*s\"%s\": {\n", indent, "", $0
    next
}

!numDates && /^[[:space:]]/ {
    numDates = split($0,dates)
    next
}

numDates && match($0,"[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){"numDates"}$") {
    indent += inStep
    printf "%s%*s\"%s\": {\n", (numItems++ ? ",\n" : ""), indent, "", substr($0,1,RSTART-1)

    indent += inStep
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    for ( i=1; i<=numDates; i++ ) {
        printf "%*s\"%s\": \"%s\"%s\n", indent, "", dates[i], $i, (i<numDates ? "," : "")
    }
    indent -= inStep

    printf "%*s}", indent, ""
    indent -= inStep
}

END {
    printf "\n%*s}\n", indent, ""
    print "}"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{
    "Balance_sheet for AAPL": {
        "Treasury Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "0.0",
            "2022-09-30": "NaN",
            "2021-09-30": "NaN",
            "2020-09-30": "NaN"
        },
        "Ordinary Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "15550061000.0",
            "2022-09-30": "15943425000.0",
            "2021-09-30": "16426786000.0",
            "2020-09-30": "16976763000.0"
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to handle multiple "Balance Sheet" blocks then just add this:

```
if ( numTables++ ) {
    printf "\n%*s},\n", indent, ""
}
numDates = numItems = 0
```

immediately below the `sub()` line, e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file2
Balance_sheet for AAPL:

                                                        2023-09-30      2022-09-30      2021-09-30      2020-09-30
Treasury Shares Number                                         0.0             NaN             NaN             NaN
Ordinary Shares Number                               15550061000.0   15943425000.0   16426786000.0   16976763000.0

Balance_sheet for foo:

                                                        2023-09-30      2022-09-30      2021-09-30      2020-09-30
Treasury Shares Number                                         0.0             NaN             NaN             NaN
Ordinary Shares Number                               15550061000.0   15943425000.0   16426786000.0   16976763000.0
```

this script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    inStep = 4
    print "{"
}

sub(/:$/,"") {
    if ( numTables++ ) {
        printf "\n%*s},\n", indent, ""
    }
    numDates = numItems = 0
    indent = inStep
    printf "%*s\"%s\": {\n", indent, "", $0
    next
}

!numDates && /^[[:space:]]/ {
    numDates = split($0,dates)
    next
}

numDates && match($0,"[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){"numDates"}$") {
    indent += inStep
    printf "%s%*s\"%s\": {\n", (numItems++ ? ",\n" : ""), indent, "", substr($0,1,RSTART-1)

    indent += inStep
    $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    for ( i=1; i<=numDates; i++ ) {
        printf "%*s\"%s\": \"%s\"%s\n", indent, "", dates[i], $i, (i<numDates ? "," : "")
    }
    indent -= inStep

    printf "%*s}", indent, ""
    indent -= inStep
}

END {
    printf "\n%*s}\n", indent, ""
    print "}"
}
```

will produce this output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2
{
    "Balance_sheet for AAPL": {
        "Treasury Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "0.0",
            "2022-09-30": "NaN",
            "2021-09-30": "NaN",
            "2020-09-30": "NaN"
        },
        "Ordinary Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "15550061000.0",
            "2022-09-30": "15943425000.0",
            "2021-09-30": "16426786000.0",
            "2020-09-30": "16976763000.0"
        }
    },
    "Balance_sheet for foo": {
        "Treasury Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "0.0",
            "2022-09-30": "NaN",
            "2021-09-30": "NaN",
            "2020-09-30": "NaN"
        },
        "Ordinary Shares Number": {
            "2023-09-30": "15550061000.0",
            "2022-09-30": "15943425000.0",
            "2021-09-30": "16426786000.0",
            "2020-09-30": "16976763000.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MJSON::Fast -e '
         my $a = lines[0..1].trim-trailing;         \
         my @a = slurp.map("Date" ~ *).lines.map:   \
             *.subst(:global, / <alpha>+ % " " /, { .trans(" " => "_") } ).split(/ \s+ /);  \
         @a = [Z] @a; my %h; for 1..^@a[0].elems -> $j {   \
             %h.append: @a.[0][$j] => %(@a.map( { $_.[0] => $_.[$j] } )[1..*]) };  \ 
         put to-json( $a => %h, :sorted-keys );'   file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Given the limited "Balance Sheet" test file posted by the OP, the sheet 'pre-processing' is correspondingly limited and possibly bespoke. The first few coding lines used to massage the data into a standard format should therefore be construed as giving a 'flavor' of the Raku language, and is not meant to represent a method for handling all 'Balance Sheets'.

0. The `JSON::Fast` Raku module is loaded on the command line.
1. The first statement reads the first two lines into `$a` scalar, `trim`-ming off trailing whitespace.
2. The second statement
   **a**). `slurp`s the remainder of the file into memory,
   **b**). prepends the `"Date"` string,
   **c**). breaks everything into `lines`, **d**). each `line` is `map`ped into, in order to: **e**). `subst`itute the pattern of alphabetic letters `% " "` separated by single-character space such that (in the replacement-half) the   spaces get `trans`lated into `_` underscores, thus removing whitespace from Row Labels. Then finally **f**). the data is split on remaining `\s+` whitespace, and this (now rectangular) table is stored in the `@a` array.
3. The `@a` table is `[Z]` "zip"-transformed such that rows-become-columns and vice versa (take care if using this operator on anything other than rectangular data).
4. A hash `%h` is declared.
5. The number of "Shares" data columns is iterated over. **a**). A `%()` anonymous hash containing key-value pairs is created, each pair having a Date (row-label) as ***key*** for the corresponding "Shares" data-column ***value*** (here, using index `[1..*]` drops the superfluous "labels"-pairing).
6. Adding another level, **b**). the appropriate "Shares" (i.e. column) label become the ***key*** for the `%()` anonymous (Date/Shares) hash, which becomes the second-level ***value***. The "Date/Shares" columns-converted-to-key/values are `append`ed to the `%h` hash.
7. Finally (really level **c** at this point), the `$a` "Balance_Sheet" header is added back-in as ***key*** to the `%h` hash as ***value***, and this (now multi-level) final hash-table is converted `to-json()`, adding the `:sorted-keys` named argument, and out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
Balance_sheet for AAPL:

                                                        2023-09-30      2022-09-30      2021-09-30      2020-09-30
Treasury Shares Number                                         0.0             NaN             NaN             NaN
Ordinary Shares Number                               15550061000.0   15943425000.0   16426786000.0   16976763000.0
```

Sample Input Table after `[Z]` transform (minus "Balance_Sheet" header line):

```
(Date Treasury_Shares_Number Ordinary_Shares_Number)
(2023-09-30 0.0 15550061000.0)
(2022-09-30 NaN 15943425000.0)
(2021-09-30 NaN 16426786000.0)
(2020-09-30 NaN 16976763000.0)
```

Final `JSON` Output:

```
{
  "Balance_sheet for AAPL:": {
    "Ordinary_Shares_Number": {
      "2020-09-30": "16976763000.0",
      "2021-09-30": "16426786000.0",
      "2022-09-30": "15943425000.0",
      "2023-09-30": "15550061000.0"
    },
    "Treasury_Shares_Number": {
      "2020-09-30": "NaN",
      "2021-09-30": "NaN",
      "2022-09-30": "NaN",
      "2023-09-30": "0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

https://raku.land/cpan:TIMOTIMO/JSON::Fast
https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://docs.raku.org/
https://raku.org